# Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException signal "7"

Tags: laravel, symfony, runtimeexception

```
[2016-10-27 08:33:03] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'The process has been signaled with signal "7".' in /home/xxxx/yyyy/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:371
```

any help PLZ

i dont find signal "7" in any question before

Comment: Have to be more specific than that...

Comment: that's all in my log @JovanPerovic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proccess you are trying to call from php gets sigbus from the system and it is more likely that the problem is in the proccess itself, not in the symphony component.

Read about that:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_error